# Eligibility of war loot

Tags: clash-of-clans

If your clan's at war but you're not participating, do you still get share of the loot?

Comment: Why was this downvoted? It's a perfectly valid question.

Answer (score 5):

No, you get war loot only if you have been able to score at least a win in the war.

Which also means that if you are participating but have no victories, you won't get any loot.

Comment: Note just in case: A victory means scoring at least 1 star on a base.